# Pre-ordering games from the PS Store

Tags: ps4

so i'm going to pre order FIFA 17 from the store. But I'm not sure how the process of pre ordering a game works. 
Do I have to pay the whole price of  the game or just a a porcentage of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the PS Store, the full amount is *typically* collected upfront and you are unable to get a refund, except for in states where required by law.

> In most instances you pay for your pre-order when you place it and this is made clear during checkout. For a few products (mostly PlayStation VR titles) we will not debit your wallet until a few days before release. This will also be made clear at checkout.  In addition, we will email you once you checkout to confirm the details of your pre-order and whether we have taken payment immediately or will debit your wallet nearer the release date.

Source: https://www.playstation.com/en-au/get-help/help-library/store---transactions/pre-orders/playstation-store-pre-orders/